# MySql query to fetch data by Month or Year

Tags: mysql, database

I want to fetch data by month or year for example if year=2015 than all data of this year or if month-year=September 2015 than only a month's data.
Their is column in which i am storing date(MySql DataType is DATE),which format is **2015-09-25** . ***So what is Mysql query for it?***

Comment: You should not stroe dates as formated string. use date type instead

Comment: @OP: Can you add to your post result of `show create table your_table_name` ?

Comment: Which format of date you have used to store in database?

Comment: @Jens If i add dates as string format for example (dd/mm/yyyy),than how i can fetch by month or year??

Comment: @VivekGondliya as i mentioned you should not do it!

Comment: @Jens If i use DATE datatype than ??

Comment: @VivekGondliya Then you can use function MONTH(), YEAR()

Comment: @VivekGondliya If you use datetype than will be able to use `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateColumn)` & `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateColumn)` functions also to compare month and year.

Comment: @KrutiPatel  will you help me to make a SQL query???

Comment: @VivekGondliya Ya sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query. You can add any month or Year by just changing value in ''.For example if you want to get record which month is 2 and year is 2012,just do following query. Just only Highlighted things are important.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
 WHERE YEAR('**2012**-09-28') = YEAR(required_date)
  and MONTH('2015-**02**-28') = MONTH(required_date);

required_date = Your Column Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the MySQL date functions like [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month), [YEAR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) provided the dates are stored in Date datatype.

As you commented in Java:

```
String date = "Fri Sep 25 10:38:42 IST 2015";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH); 
SimpleDateFormat newsdf =new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
```

Comment: what is mysql query? for example i want to fetch data which month and year is Feb-2015.

Comment: @VivekGondliya:- As you discussed with Jens above, if you will use the `date` datatype and store it as dd/mm/yyyy then you can simply write in sql as `MONTH(yourDateColumn)` and `YEAR(yourDateColumn)`. **On a side note:**  *It is recommended to store dates as Date datatype so as to avoid these kinds of formatting issues and other date type calculations.*